# Multiple platform projects and NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have created a library that I need to be able to use in a Portable Class Library as well as a regular .NET application. The way I accomplished this is by creating multiple solutions / projects that point to the same files:

```
Src/
    Dismissile.sln
    Dismissile.Portable.sln
    Dismissile/
        Dismissile.csproj
        Dismissile.Portable.csproj
        Class1.cs
```

Dismissile.sln includes Dismissile.csproj and targets .NET Framework 4.5.2
Dismissile.Portable.sln includes Dismissile.Portable.csproj and is a portable class library project that targets .NET Framework 4.5, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.

Each project includes Class1.cs. I have created some conditional compilation symbols in each project such as PORTABLE and NET452.

This seems to work so fine but now I need to add a NuGet package for JSON.NET into my projects.

If I add a NuGet package in my Portable project it will create the following in my packages.config:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable40-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
```

However, if I add it in my other project it will create the following in packages.config:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Is there any way to have a separate packages.config so each project includes the correct reference to my NuGet dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for this scenario is to create distinct folders for every project and include the *.cs*-files via a link. (see [MSDN - Add as Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082.aspx))

Doing so enables you to reference different packages (and versions) for different platforms (projects), as you have distinct *packages.config*-files.

Additionally, I should mention that you may encounter incompatible framework methods (such as `Task.Factory.StartNew` for NET40 and `Task.Run` for NET45), which can be solved in two different ways:

**Working with compiler constants**

Define a framework contstant in your projects, and query them with [preprocessor-directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx), like:

```
#if NET40
Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
#elif NET45
Task.Run(...)
#endif
```

**Working with partial classes and methods**

*Dismissile.NET40\FooClass.cs*

```
public partial class Foo
{
  public void Bar()
  {
    // ...
    this.RunTask(task);
  }

  partial void RunTask(Task task);
}
```

*Dismissile.NET40\Partial.FooClass.cs*

```
public partial class Foo
{
  partial RunTask(Task task)
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(task);
  }
}
```

*Dismissile.NET45\Partial.FooClass.cs*

```
public partial class Foo
{
  partial RunTask(Task task)
  {
    Task.Run(task);
  }
}
```

**Summary**

My preferred solution is *partial classes and methods*, as they don't mess up your source with nestings (due to `#if`-statements), stepping while debugging is way more natural, and finally this approach is more flexible for complicated scenarios.

Comment: Is there any caveat that I need to be aware of when adding the files as links? Anything I can't do? Also, could my main .NET project file still exist in the folder that all the .cs files are in and then just create separate projects for the other platforms?

Comment: The crucial point is to have different folders for every platform to have distinct *packages.config*-files. There might be issues w/ framework methods (as their signature, availability, ... may differ), but this can be solved with compiler constants and `#if`-statements or partial classes, where you provide framework specific implementations in a non-shared partial class.

Comment: Right, but would you have a separate folder for all the .cs files with no project in that folder, and then create another folder for the project file and add links, and another folder for the portable project and add links, or would it be okay to have a folder with the cs files and a project without links, then another folder for the portable project that uses links.

Comment: That strongly depends on your mood :) I always went for the following option (I dunno if that's the optimal solution, though): Create a project for .NET40 and implement my logic there, then create .NET45 and add links (and adapt framework specific implementations). Furthermore, you should clean the framework from your namespace in your project settings.